# Xcode 5 & OSX Mavericks Compiling for iOS6.1 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6.1, osx-mavericks

This used to work pre Mavericks installation. Now i'm finding that even though I have copied over the 6.1SDK and I am targeting 6.1 using Base SDK, app is running using iOS7 ui elements and layout. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Are you running on a iOS7 device or the simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like most issues can be solved by setting the Editor version to 'Xcode 4.6' in interface builder when you have the storyboard selected.

Answer (score 1):

you need to copy the 6.1SDK to below path

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

and you need to download the 6.1 simulator Xcode > preferences> downloads[image]

Comment: I have already copied over the SDK but I shouldn't need to install the iOS6.1 simulator. I want to run my app compiled against 6.1 on 7.

Comment: @Imran create ipa using iOS 6.1 and flashed on iOS 7 device and check. It will retain the iOS 6.1 UI components

Comment: Thanks rocker, I'm aware of that method but its a bit inconvenient i want to be able to use the simulator and Xcode 5.

Comment: @Imran yes it is, That why i suggest you to download the iOS6.1 simulator.

Comment: I need to test my app compiled against SDK 6.1, using the iOS7 simulator, so simulating running my app running on iOS7. If i use the 6.1 simulator it will be like running it on a non iOS7 device.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Settings, did you change your Deployment target to 6.1? You should set your Base SDK to 7.0 and Deployment target to 6.1.

Comment: yup changed both base SDK and deployment target to 6.1